# re-render/refresh parent class component from child class component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have parent and child class component, and want to update the parent component from child component. But I am getting the followig error.
The actuall code file is too large that's why I did not mention the whole code but try to explain how I am doing.

Thank you

**parent component:**

```
export class parent extends React.Component {
      .....

componentDidMount() {

 A();

}

 A() {
  this.B();
}

 B() {
 .......
}

render() {
  return (
   <child a = {this.A} />
)}

}
```

**child component:**

```
export class parent extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount() {
    C();
   }
   
   C() {
   
   .....(other functionality)
   this.props.a();
  }
}
```

**Error:** Uncaught TypeError: this.B is not a function

Comment: You are calling function `B();` Where is your function definition like `B() {}`?

Comment: Sorry, I edit it. you can see the defination of fucntion

Answer (score 0):

your function `A(){}` lost context, when you pass it via link,

to fix it use class property declaration and arror function

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  A = ()=> {
    this.B();
  }
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `parent component` defined type of function `B()` is incorrect.

**parent component:**

```
export class parent extends React.Component {
      .....

B() { // define it like this here

} 

A = () => { // define `A` as an arrow function as you pass it like `this.A` instead of `() => this.A()`
  this.B();
}

render() {
  return (
   <child a = {this.A} />
  )
}

}
```